Identity Server 4 add saml2 client
We have an identity server 4 as our identity provider. It uses openId and we have all the clients configured using the OpenId protocol. We have a portal that uses one of these clients for authentication and retrieves logged-in user details from the id token. Now this portal has a link for users to reach another portal that uses Saml2 authentication. We have to SSO into the second portal (saml2 one) from the first portal (OpenId one).
Now in identity server we have added Saml2 support, it downloads xml document when we go https:///Saml2.
But, metadata endpoint is not working, even if we have set LoadMetadata true in the implementation.
Below is the implementation:
var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication().AddSaml2(options =>
                {
                    string baseUrl = configuration.GetSection("AdminConfiguration")["BaseUrl"].ToString();
                    options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId(new Uri(baseUrl + "Saml2").ToString());
                    options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                        new IdentityProvider(
                            new EntityId(new Uri(baseUrl + "Metadata").ToString()), options.SPOptions)
                        {
                            LoadMetadata = true
                        });
                    var certificateConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(nameof(CertificateConfiguration)).Get<CertificateConfiguration>();
                    var path = certificateConfiguration.SigningCertificatePfxFilePath;
                    Console.WriteLine("EntityId: " + options.SPOptions.EntityId.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("Path: " + path);
                    var absolutePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, path.Replace("~/", "").TrimStart('/'));
                    Console.WriteLine("Absolute Path: " + absolutePath);
                    options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(absolutePath, certificateConfiguration.SigningCertificatePfxFilePassword));
                });

Note: We are using  Sustainsys.Saml2; NugetPackage
We have added a client to our identity server
We got to know we have to load second portal's (saml2 IP) metadata file to the first portal (openid identity proider). Can someone please help us how to load this metadata file?
Are we missing anything in the implemtation?
